# Hide grid column with the rest of columns redistributing

Tags: html, css, css-grid

everyone.

I'm trying to implement the grid column that hides when the wrapping container width goes below certain value, while the rest of columns should redistribute over the entire width:

[image]

Neither `visibility: hidden`, nor `display: none` for *disappearing* column did work (since the blank space is left in place of removed column, while the left column doesn't take the whole width).

My question is: how do I achieve desired behavior with pure CSS and without modifying `grid-template-columns` of the parent grid container?

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(100px, 1fr));
}

.column {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.columnA {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
}

.columnB {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 4;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .columnA {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="columnA column">columnA</div>
  <div class="columnB column">columnB</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplify your code like below:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap:5px;
  grid-auto-columns: minmax(100px, 1fr); /* size of one column */
  grid-auto-flow:column; /* column flow */
}

.column {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.columnB {
  grid-column:span 2; /* B takes 2 columns */
} 

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .columnA {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="columnA column">columnA</div>
  <div class="columnB column">columnB</div>
</div>
```

If you want to keep the template (which is not needed) you can do like below:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap:5px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(100px, 1fr));
}

.column {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.columnB {
  grid-column:span 2;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .columnA {
    display:none;
  }
  .columnB {
    grid-column:span 3; /* B will take 3 columns when A is hidden */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="columnA column">columnA</div>
  <div class="columnB column">columnB</div>
</div>
```